# Maven - How to include single java files as sources/depedencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a multi-module project in maven which is as follows:

```
root/pom.xml
|________client/pom.xml
         |________/src/main/java
         |________/src/main/resources
|________common/pom.xml
         |________/src/main/java
|________tools/pom.xml
         |________/src/main/java
|________server/pom.xml
         |________/src/main/java
         |________/src/main/resources
```

I would like to compile the **"client"** module code which depends on *ALL java classes* in **"common"** module but on *SOME java classes* in the **"tools"** module.
Using the **build-helper-maven-plugin** as below, I was able to add all java source files under **common/** path, but I need a way to define individual java files as sources which are under **tools/**.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>../common/src/main/java</source>
                    <!-- Adding single java files as below does not work -->
                    <source>../tools/log/Log.java</source>
                    <source>../tools/socket/SocketClient.java</source>
                    <!----------------------------------------------------->
                </sources>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
```

Comment: This will simply not work cause your structure is simply wrong. You should make module which comprises of the classes which are needed by other modules. This could result in a number of small modules which contain only one or two classes but that makes it easier to reuse the modules and opens the way to go with Maven dependencies etc. Also helps later on to improve build performance etc. Buthelper is simply the wrong way.

Comment: Just make a separate module `common-one` where only those classes are part of and then you can add a dependency to that module via Maven's pom file and that's it...

Answer (score 1):

You should include module "common" and "tools" as dependency in "client"
Then you can run build in the root of project: mvn clean install - it will build all modules.

Comment: Tools module has java files that are needed by client and others needed by server module. Out of 100 java files in tools, i need to use 10 specific ones for client. I do not need to include all of them cause many are irrelevant and depend also on other classes that i do not need

Comment: So you will fight against Maven which is a combat you will loose... simply clean up your structure and follow best practices instead of circumvent them because you believe you know it better ....

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use parts of a module as dependency. Maven does not support this and it results in brittle and hard to maintain constructions.

If you only need parts of `tools`, then this is a clear signal that `tools` is too large and you need to split it up into two modules.

Comment: Not exactly. Tools has various tools that may be used or not from any other module. It’s like a big jar with many functions but I need to use only the necessary ones to keep size small, keeping out what is unnecessary. Before using maven I could achieve this on eclipse through “link source” feature, whereas I could link individual files as part of the project

Comment: In Maven it does not make sense to use parts of a dependency. Either you split `tools` up or you live with the stuff you don't need. Usually it does not matter too much if you have 10 or 100 additional classes. If dependencies are the problem, I would exclude some dependencies of `tools`.

Comment: Eclipse and Maven are complete different things. Eclipse is a bad build tool which can't be automated where Maven is exactly for that purpose ...It looks like someone has made a transformation to Maven only half backed and not really correctly understood what is needed ... Furthermore fat jar are a path to other problems which you don't like to have....(too long to explain that in the comments.) ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the comments received it seems that the ideal solution is to break the modules into sub-modules and use those as dependencies. However, as this is currently a time consuming task, I am posting a quick and dirty solution on how you can include one or more java files into your build by copying the files under a new source directory, **src/main/external**, and then add this directory as part of your sources.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-source-java-files</id>
                  <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>src/main/external</outputDirectory>
                     <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                     <resources>
                        <resource>
                           <!-- External source directory -->
                           <directory>../tools/src/main/java/</directory>
                           <includes>
                              <!-- Files to be copied along with their directory paths -->
                              <include>tools/log/Log.java</include>
                              <include>tools/socket/SocketClient.java</include>
                              <include>tools/client/reader/**</include>
                           </includes>
                        </resource>
                     </resources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                            <source>src/main/resources</source>
                            <source>../common/src/main/java</source>
                            <!-- Here we add the source with the files copied -->
                            <source>src/main/external</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

The output after compilation would be as follows:

```
root/pom.xml
|________client/pom.xml
         |________/src/main/java
         |________/src/main/resources
         |________/src/main/external  <----- This contains all external java files.
```